# Creating trend data from data that has start and end date spaning days

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using C#, NHibernate, Fluent NHibernate and LINQ (repository pattern).

**Fictional story on what I want to do**

Say I have a car parking place, so I have a car that is renting a space from date until date. This becomes one entry into the database.

I would like to find out how many cars there were for each day over the period of last 30 days. So data that can be used in a trend chart.

**Description**

What I have is entries in the database that are like so:

```
Entry:
--------
ID
StartDate
EndDate
```

I need to find out how many entries there were `each day` for a time period (say `last 30 days`).

If I have say this data in the database:

```
ID | Start      | End
---|------------|----------
1  | 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-01
2  | 2013-01-02 | 2013-01-02
3  | 2013-01-02 | 2013-01-03 <-- NOTICE
4  | 2013-01-03 | 2013-01-03
5  | 2013-01-03 | 2013-01-05 <-- NOTICE
6  | 2013-01-04 | 2013-01-05
```

I have date range `2013-01-01` until `2013-01-05`.

I except the result:

```
Date       | Value | Entry IDs (not part of the result, only here for clarity)
-----------|-------|-----------
2013-01-01 | 1     | 1
2013-01-02 | 2     | 2 3
2013-01-03 | 3     | 3 4 5
2013-01-04 | 2     | 5 6
2013-01-05 | 2     | 5 6
```

I currently only group by `startdate` and then get the numbers, but this is invalid now because of this new requirement that was added with `enddate`.

I could do a for each day in that range, try to find entries that match in that, but I'm thinking that would be too expensive on the database or web service.

Advices?

Comment: Because thats the domain, it can be 700 entries for one day, it does not matter, i've shorten the details so it would only have the needed data.

Comment: my bad, i'll update :)

Comment: I checked and 2013-01-04 and 2013-01-05 seems fine: 

Entry 5 goes from 2013-01-03 until 2013-01-05 which makes 3 days:
2013-01-03
2013-01-04
2013-01-05

Entry 6 goes from 2013-01-04 until 2013-01-05 which makes 2 days:
2013-01-04
2013-01-05

So 2013-01-04 becomes 2: entries: 5 and 6.
So 2013-01-05 becomes 2: entries: 5 and 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var start = new DateTime(2013, 01, 01);
var end = DateTime(2013, 01, 05);

var q = d.Query()
         .Where(x =>
             x.Date >= start
             && end >= x.Date) // there you filter for range 
         .GroupBy(x => x.Date); // use .Day to group by day
```

Start time and end time are inclusive.

**EDIT**

I've found this (actually i've a similar case in my project):

```
var start = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
var end = new DateTime(2013, 1, 5);
var current = start;
var ranges = new List<DateTime>();

while (current <= end)
{
    ranges.Add(current);

    current = current.AddDays(1);
}

var res = ranges.Select(x => new
{
    date = x,
    entries = entries.Where(e => e.Start <= x && x <= e.End).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Try test it and maybe you can acomodate to your case (note that filtering starts by the date range).

Comment: This does assume I have a `DateCreated` column, I don't have that. Your **not** understanding my question. I want to find out, for each day, how many entries are there that are in that day. So I can create a trend chart.

Comment: I still don't have the column `DateCreated`, even if I had it, it would not help me with the question I have. It will give me the wrong trend if I group by this column if I had it. I could have grouped by StartDate and got the wrong result for several days if I ran it like that.

Comment: I updated the question with a story if that makes it more clear.

Comment: I have a question on this one, if I select 6 months, wont that give me some what in the pluss of 360 where clauses only for dates? or do you mean to do this in memory?

Comment: We use it only on short periods (15-30 days) and have no problems, but for larger periods you have to test how works.

Comment: This would work, mark it as answered, but will check out the performance challenges. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) to calculate the trend data:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
class CarPeriod : DayTimeRange
{

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------
  public CarPeriod( int id, DateTime start, DateTime end ) :
    this( id, start, end.Date.AddDays( 1 ).Subtract( start.Date ).Days )
  {
  } // CarPeriod

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------
  public CarPeriod( int id, DateTime start, int days ) :
    base( start.Year, start.Month, start.Day, days )
  {
    Id = id;
  } // CarPeriod

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------
  public int Id { get; private set; }

} // class CarPeriod

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[Sample( "DaysTrendData" )]
public void DaysTrendData()
{
  // periods
  ITimePeriodCollection carPeriods = new TimePeriodCollection();
  carPeriods.Add( new CarPeriod( 1, new DateTime( 2013, 1, 1 ), new DateTime( 2013, 1, 1 ) ) );
  carPeriods.Add( new CarPeriod( 2, new DateTime( 2013, 1, 2 ), new DateTime( 2013, 1, 2 ) ) );
  carPeriods.Add( new CarPeriod( 3, new DateTime( 2013, 1, 2 ), new DateTime( 2013, 1, 3 ) ) );
  carPeriods.Add( new CarPeriod( 4, new DateTime( 2013, 1, 3 ), new DateTime( 2013, 1, 3 ) ) );
  carPeriods.Add( new CarPeriod( 5, new DateTime( 2013, 1, 3 ), new DateTime( 2013, 1, 5 ) ) );
  carPeriods.Add( new CarPeriod( 6, new DateTime( 2013, 1, 4 ), new DateTime( 2013, 1, 5 ) ) );

  Days testDays = new Days( new DateTime( 2013, 1, 1 ), 5 );
  foreach ( Day testDay in testDays.GetDays() )
  {
    Console.Write( "Day: " + testDay + ": " );
    foreach ( CarPeriod carPeriod in carPeriods )
    {
      if ( carPeriod.IntersectsWith( testDay ) )
      {
        Console.Write( carPeriod.Id + " " );
      }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
} // DaysTrendData
```