# MongoDB - How to make trends with start and end date?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So what I have are entries in the database that have a `StartDate` and a `EndDate` that could `span several days` or could be just on the `same day`.

What I want to do is that if a entry have start date `2014-01-02` and end date `2014-01-06`, I want that to have a value on each of the days: `2014-01-02`, `2014-01-03`, `2014-01-04`, `2014-01-05` and `2014-01-06`. This then plugs into a nice trend chart.

Note: same as a question I have asked before for C#: [Creating trend data from data that has start and end date spaning days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847885/creating-trend-data-from-data-that-has-start-and-end-date-spaning-days).

Currently I have created this aggregation, but it does not handle entries that span over several days:

```
db.details.aggregate(
    {
        '$match': {
            Car: "A1",
            StartDate: { "$lte": new Date("2013-10-30") },
            EndDate: { "$gte": new Date("2013-10-29") }
        }
    },
    {
        '$group' : {
            '_id' : {
                year: { '$year' : '$StartDate'},
                month: {'$month' : '$StartDate' },
                day: {'$dayOfMonth' : '$StartDate' }
            },
            'date': { '$first': '$StartDate' },
            'sum' : { '$sum' : 1 }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I doubt that you will be able to do this with aggregation. I think you will need MapReduce to generate the missing values between the start-date and the end-date.

Comment: I would question as well whether you really want to do this on the database end. Your application can generate this data from the start & end dates. If this is too slow I would look to keep this information pre-computed, maintaining at the time of data insertion.

Comment: What about you place a few objects so we can understand the schema?

Comment: { car: "A1", startDate: "2013-01-01", endDate: "2013-01-03" }, { car: "A2", startDate: "2013-01-02", endDate: "2013-01-05" }